# what do these sentences suggest? "she doesn't like me, even if I like her" "she wouldn't like me, even if I liked her"

Tags: sentence-construction, difference, conjunctions

> She doesn't like me,  even if I like her.
> She wouldn't like me, even if I liked her
> She doesn't like me,  although I like her

which do hint that I like her or not? I knew that "although" is followed by a fact, so the third must do so, right?

Comment: They all hint that you like her. Why else have the conversation?

Comment: (1b) "She doesn't like me, even though I like her" makes more sense than (1), just showing a perhaps unexpected (_even_ though) contrast. (3) is similar, but doesn't comment on the contrast (no _even_). (2) shows the 'B wouldn't be the case even if A were true' form of sentence (with a strong hint that it isn't, though the utterance  could be fishing).

Comment: They suggest you’re in for a rough time.

Answer (score 1):

The first *hints* that you like her. It raises a *hypothetical*,which you hint might be true, or at least might become true.

The second gives a *counterfactual*.  You are claiming that you don't like her (but you could be lying).  The use of the past tense indicates that this is counterfactual.

The last is explicit. It states that you do like her.  (but, again, you could be lying)

As noted in comments "She doesn't like me, even though I like her" is better, and more explicit.